# $L^2$ estimate and a nonlinear logarithmic transformation

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\phi$ satisfy
$$
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\phi_t = \phi_{xx}, & t>0, \ x \in (0,1) \\
\phi(0,\cdot) = \phi_0, & x \in (0,1)\\
\phi(t,0) = a(t), \ \phi(t,1) = b(t), & t >0.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$ and $\psi$ satisfy
$$
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\psi_{xx} = 0, & x \in (0,1) \\
\psi(0) = \alpha, \ \psi(1) = \beta, & t >0.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$
Suppose that we know for some $t \in (0,T)$ that
$$
\|\phi(t,\cdot)-\psi\|_{L^2}  + \|a-\alpha\|_{L^2} +  \|b-\beta\|_{L^2}  \le C(e^{-t}-e^{-(T-t)}) \quad\quad\quad (*)
$$
Can we prove that
the same inequality holds for
$$\tilde \phi = -2 \,\partial_x(\log(\phi))$$
and
$$\tilde \psi = -2 \,\partial_x(\log(\psi))$$
? If not, how can we estimate
$$\|\tilde \phi(t,\cdot)-\tilde\psi\|_{L^2}$$ assuming (*)?

Comment: Are $a$ and $a(t)$ related in any way?

Comment: @K.defaoite Thanks! I've edited the question to include the info that I forgot.